# What are the cohomology groups of Moore space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am using the following definition of Moore space:

**Definition:**

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $n$ an integer $\geq 2.$ A Moore space of type $(G,n)$ is $1-$connected, $CW-$complex $X$ such that:

$$ \widetilde{H}_i(X) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & if \, i \neq n, \\
      G &  if   i = n. 
   \end{cases} $$

And I want to find:

$1- H_*(M(\mathbb Z_{p^a}, 2); \mathbb Z).$

$2- H^*(M(\mathbb Z_{p^a}, 2); \mathbb Z).$

$3- H_*(M(\mathbb Z_{p^a}, 2) \mathbb Z_{p^t}).$

$4- H^*(M(\mathbb Z_{p^a}, 2); \mathbb Z_{p^t}).$

**My answers are:**

1-Using the given definition of Moore space, I can tell that  $H_0 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \widetilde{H_0}$ and $H_i = \widetilde{H_i} \text{ for } i \geq 1.$Is that correct?

2- I do not know what are the cohomology groups of Moore space, could anyone tell me a source where I can find this information calculated? I know that it can be calculated using chain complex, but is not there any easier way of calculating it? I want to know what the final groups should be.

3- I know that, knowing $(1,)$ we can use the UCT for homology to calculate $H_*(M(\mathbb Z_{p^a}, 2); \mathbb Z_{p^t}).$ correct?

4- I know that, knowing $(2,)$ we can use the UCT for cohomology to calculate $H^*(M(\mathbb Z_{p^a}, 2); \mathbb Z_{p^t}).$ correct?

**Could anyone help me in answering those questions, specifically question 2?**

Comment: The standard construction of a Moore space gives you a very nice and explicit cellular chain complex from which to compute all that you want (you can use the universal coefficients theorem for finite coefficients).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is correct.

2-4. Yes, the UCT makes it a purely algebraic exercise. But I think you misunderstand the UCT because in fact all 2-4 follow from (1) by it, in particular both (2) and (4). For (3) there will be $H_* \otimes -$ and $Tor(H_*, -)$ and for (2) and (4) there will be $Hom(H_*, -)$ and $Ext(H_*, -)$. Note that both times only homology groups are used.

Comment: Do you know a source that contains the cohomology groups of Moore space?

Comment: But in case of abelian groups the $Ext$ part is 0. Correct?

Comment: Just plug your data into the formula, see T3.2. on p.195 in Hatcher, for instance. Ext is not necessarily 0 for abelian groups. On the same very page of Hatcher it is explained how to compute Exts.

Comment: but in our 3,4 cases the coefficient is a field and the CW complex is of finite type then $Ext$ is zero. while in 2, $Ext$ is not zero .... am I correct?

Comment: Ext with a field is not always 0 (e.g. $Ext(\mathbb Z_{p}, \mathbb Z_{p}) = \mathbb Z_{p}$), and also $\mathbb Z_{p^t}$ is not a field for $t>1$.

Comment: I think you should be careful with how you phrase this. Ext over a field always vanishes, i.e. the underlying ring is a field. Ext over the integers of fields need not vanish, which is what you say. I know you know this, but in case someone reading does not.

Comment: Fair, "with" might be a bit ambiguous in this context.